# Not receiving webhook callbacks from PayPal

Tags: paypal, callback, sinatra, paypal-webhooks

I have a sinatra app which is set up like this:

```
class AppName < Sinatra::Base
#...
    post '/paypalhook' do
        puts "got info about something from paypal"
        puts params.inspect

        return params.to_s
    end
#...
end
```

Now, when I create my own `POST`s to this url, it works. However, when I go into [webhooks simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/webhooksSimulator) on PayPal, I never receive anything. **What am I doing wrong?** Why isn't this simple thing working?

---

Notes:
The webserver is hosted with custom .com domain. It is set up with SSL termination in nginx (aka. It uses `https`), and routed through cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it, it's working for me. Can you try again and make sure you select an event type.

Comment: I have selected an event type. I do get the "Event Status. Your event has been successfully queued at Mon, May 11 2015 11:52:11 GMT" But my logs don't show any sign of any events coming in. If I manually do a POST request to the same URL I do see it show up in the log, so there does not seem to be anything coming in.

Comment: Can you try to call webhook simulator API? You can find the doc here

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#notifications

Share the debug id in response header. We will check it for you.

Comment: @Alex, I have the same problem.  the debug Id is d061caecd1087, could you please have a check? thanks

Comment: @Alex I am trying to do a completely basic access to the paypal api now, and I am getting an error with code: `7f0fe04cb3f21`. I am trying to follow this [make your first api call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/) and it is failing.

Comment: @Alex . I assume you work for PayPal. Can you check this out? This is still unresolved.